# ssl error with nodemailer sending email as sendgrid

Tags: node.js, firebase, sendgrid, nodemailer

I'm using NodeMailer v: 6.9.7 on nodejs v:18.x.x to send email with SendGrid, but I'm encountering this error:

[Error: C0E743FEB83E0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:354:
] {
library: 'SSL routines',
reason: 'wrong version number',
code: 'ESOCKET',
command: 'CONN'
}
below I'm pasting the definition of the transport i have created to send email with SendGrid:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "SendGrid",
  secure:true,
  auth: {
    // TODO: replace `user` and `pass` values from <https://forwardemail.net>
    api_key: sendgridApiKey.value(),
    //user: sendgridApiKey.value()
  }
});
```

can you help resolve this error? if it might help as information im deploying the email sending as a cloud function on firebase